# Create an efficient data structure for an order book

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

I built an NFT marketplace in solidity with Sell, Buy, and Ask orders stored in arrays.
I've done some quick test to send a lot of transactions to this contract and fill the arrays with buy orders, and the gas usage of the functions got quite high after a lot of orders as I need to iterate over the array.

Are they any solution to solve this issue, like maybe using a mapping ?

The issue with the mapping is that I wanna store the orders in a data structure that would be easy to reach from the frontend, like an array...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Edit: I'm building on a low gas price Blockchain, so the price is not the issue but rather block limit and also to have the peace of mind of having a clean and optimized code

Comment: Can you show the code used for adding orders? If the gas get higher with usage it is likely an array/mapping iteration. I'd try to remove the iteration.

Comment: Indeed, you're right!
That was in the case of an auction, for each buy order placed, I was iterating over all past buy orders to get the maximum price, and make sure that the entered value was greater than the biggest order.
I've went to this solution because the array was not ordered because of the way I was deleting element (replacing the element at index by the last element, and `.pop()`)
Instead, I will just push the last buy order and assume that it's the highest one.
Thanks

Comment: Is it a good practice to iterate over orders on the client side and send the transaction accordingly if enough safety checks are made in the smart contract in case of cancelling an order ?

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid any iteration in the contract, also you shouldn't rely on the users will be doing the "right" thing.

Comment: I see. So I need to find a whole new contract architecture. 
I think that I need to take the problem at the root and find an efficient data structure tree, but don't know which one to implement in a smart contract.
Let's take a concrete example: A sale has been finished and executed by the seller. How not to iterate over an array of order to refund all participants ?
Making the users cancel each of their orders may make the UX worse :/

Comment: I'd suggest to look at existing projects that are similar to yours, perhaps 0x protocol, or uniswap, etc. Or some other projects that have to manage rebalancing tokens, like olympus dao, etc.